# Looping through CSV and parsing a JSON query using each result

Tags: php, json, parsing, csv

So despite hours of fiddling I cannot understand why my JSON query only returns a result for the last line in the CSV/TXT files I am trying to parse.

Here is the code:

```
//Enter API Key Here
$api_key = 'AIzaSyB9Dq3w1HCxkS5qyELI_pZuTmdK8itOBHo';
$origin = 'RG12 1AA';
$output_type = 'json'; //xml or json
$csv_location = 'http://www.naturedock.co.uk/postcodes.csv';

//Do not edit
$base_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/';
$origin_url = '?origin=';
$destination_url = '&destination=';
$end_url = '&sensor=false&key=';

$page = join("",file("$csv_location"));
$kw = explode("\n", $page);

for($i=0;$i<count($kw);$i++){
    $destination = $kw[$i];
    echo $destination;
    $raw_url = $base_url . $output_type . $origin_url . $origin . $destination_url . $destination . $end_url . $api_key;
    $request_url = str_replace(' ', '', $raw_url);

    $getJson = file_get_contents($request_url);
    $routes = json_decode($getJson);

    $result = $routes->routes[0]->legs[0]->distance->value;
    echo $result . '<br>';
}
```

The result I get looks like this:

```
Distance by Post Code Generator v0.1 by Phil Hughes 

RG12 0GA 
RG12 0GB 
RG12 0GC 
RG12 0GD4066
```

Where the '4066' is the correct variable for RG12 0GD postcode but none of the others return results as you can see.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
join("",file("$csv_location"));
```

concatenated all lines feom the file to a single line without separator. The following explode() sees no newlines any more. So you are working on one line only. count($kw) always evaluates to 1 and your loop runs only one time.